# how do use the javascript code for pagespeed insights api to display results for my website

Tags: javascript, api

i want to integrate the pagespeedinsights api to my website : 
http://ccit324.firebird.sheridanc.on.ca/

ive tried putting the url into the js code shown in this website 
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/get-started

how do I put my website link into this code so that the PageSpeedInsight API works.
   the code:

```
   <script>      
   function run() {
   const url = setUpQuery();
   fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {

  showInitialContent(json.id);
  const cruxMetrics = {
    "First Contentful Paint": json.loadingExperience.metrics.FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS.category,
    "First Input Delay": json.loadingExperience.metrics.FIRST_INPUT_DELAY_MS.category
  };
  showCruxContent(cruxMetrics);
  const lighthouse = json.lighthouseResult;
  const lighthouseMetrics = {
    'First Contentful Paint': lighthouse.audits['first-contentful-paint'].displayValue,
    'Speed Index': lighthouse.audits['speed-index'].displayValue,
    'Time To Interactive': lighthouse.audits['interactive'].displayValue,
    'First Meaningful Paint': lighthouse.audits['first-meaningful-paint'].displayValue,
    'First CPU Idle': lighthouse.audits['first-cpu-idle'].displayValue,
    'Estimated Input Latency': lighthouse.audits['estimated-input-latency'].displayValue
  };
  showLighthouseContent(lighthouseMetrics);
});
 }

 function setUpQuery() {
 const api = 
'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed';
const parameters = {
url: encodeURIComponent('https://developers.google.com')
 };
let query = `${api}?`;
for (key in parameters) {
query += `${key}=${parameters[key]}`;
 }
return query;
 }

function showInitialContent(id) {
document.body.innerHTML = '';
const title = document.createElement('h1');
title.textContent = 'PageSpeed Insights API Demo';
document.body.appendChild(title);
const page = document.createElement('p');
page.textContent = `Page tested: ${id}`;
document.body.appendChild(page);
}

function showCruxContent(cruxMetrics) {
const cruxHeader = document.createElement('h2');
cruxHeader.textContent = "Chrome User Experience Report Results";
document.body.appendChild(cruxHeader);
for (key in cruxMetrics) {
const p = document.createElement('p');
p.textContent = `${key}: ${cruxMetrics[key]}`;
document.body.appendChild(p);
}
}

 function showLighthouseContent(lighthouseMetrics) {
const lighthouseHeader = document.createElement('h2');
lighthouseHeader.textContent = "Lighthouse Results";
document.body.appendChild(lighthouseHeader);
for (key in lighthouseMetrics) {
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = `${key}: ${lighthouseMetrics[key]}`;
  document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
  }

 run();
</script>
```

Comment: Please read the rules on providing a minimal working example for us to see and review. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You probably need to replace and add your API key.

Comment: Hello and welcome on stackoverflow.
Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I know nothing about PageSpeed Insights API, but the code you're showing uses `https://developer.google.com` as the URL, and looks like copy-pasta from the linked "Get Started" page. Please show the *actual* code that you are attempting to run.

Comment: That is the code Im attempting to run im copying and pasting it in HTML. However, when I change the URL to my website link: http://ccit324.firebird.sheridanc.on.ca/  it doesnt provide responses

Answer (score 2):

The PageSpeed Insight will only work once every couple of seconds or minutes without an API Key, because they add a cooldown timer.

So get one from here to be able to make multiple request without a cooldown timer: [Get Started with the PageSpeed Insights API](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/get-started)

You'll want to add it at the end of the "query" request otherwise it can give a "Invalid API KEY" error.

```js
function setUpQuery() {
    const api = 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed';
    const parameters = {
        url: encodeURIComponent(`http://yourwebsite.com`)
    };

    let query = `${api}?`;
    for (key in parameters) {
    query += `${key}=${parameters[key]}`;
    }

    // Add API key at the end of the query
    query += "&key=YOUR_API_KEY"

    return query;
}
```

Now to get the results of your website. Everything will be in the `json` variable.

```js
function run() {
    const url = setUpQuery();
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        // See https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/reference/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed#response
        // to learn more about each of the properties in the response object.
        console.log(json) // ALL YOUR WEBSITE DATA WILL BE DISPLAYED IN THE CONSOLE
    });
}
```